# Ultra wide band

Tags: microcontroller, signal, bluetooth

I am working with an ultra wide band device (DWM1001 dev board) and I was wondering how does a UWB connection work? How do you connect one device to another through ultra wide band? I know that there are anchors and tags and the tags report back their locations to the anchors, but how is this connection established initially? For example, my DWM1001 dev board has an UWB address. Is it similar to Bluetooth where you can just connect the device through its address? And if so how?

Comment: Welcome. What research have you done so far? Have you worked out any block diagrams?

Comment: @Sparky256 I have been doing research on and following guides on UWB. The board that I described above has built in UWB modules into it, and I have so far connected two of these boards (an anchor and a tag) together to get the tag's position. This was used with the boards built in firmware. Specifically, I wanted to see if there was a way to pass in specific UWB addresses to this module or more generally what is the process for two UWB devices to connect?

Comment: @Sparky256 try and stay focused on the question, not the OP, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Bluetooth, each device has a unique 48-bit address (see IEEE 802.15.1 standard).

[DWM1001 is an IEEE 802.15.4-2011 UWB compliant device](https://www.decawave.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/dwm1000-datasheet-1.pdf). The addressing scheme of IEEE 802.15.4-compliant devices is more elaborate; depending on frame type, 64-bit (full) and 16-bit (short) addresses may be indicated in MAC header address fields. You can see it for yourself in [DW1001 Firmware API Guide](https://www.decawave.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/DWM1001-API-Guide-2.2.pdf).

You can communicate with DWM1001 via SPI, GPIO, UART. When `ble_en ctf-tag flag` is set, you can use Bluetooth LE for communication.

On github you can find [examples (in software programming languages of your choice) of using DWM1001 hardware](https://github.com/topics/dwm1001).

There are also examples of DWM100X-based development with Arduino.

Concerning your question, "how does a UWB connection work", you can launch an Internet search "ultra wide-band technology", and start with a Wikipedia article on this subject. If you find too many an unknown words and conceptions, it is not the end of the world. For example, you may be on a computer-science side of the EECS department. Without going into a depth of communication technologies, you can still develop useful applications for radar imaging, location and tracking, RFID, and more, with the help of DWM1001 dev board and accompanying documents.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed information, I appreciate it. I have seen those resources and been using them so I appreciate this guidance. My main question though comes from your last paragraph talking about UWB connection. I was more focused on using the DWM1001 board to connect to another unique device that I had that also supports UWB. After digging around, I have not seen how that part works. If anyone had any guidance on that specific connection, that would be helpful.

Comment: Do you work with multiple DWM1001/DWM1000 boards or is your "another unique device that also supports UWB" the other type UWP device? Can you name it, or is it non-commercial, one-off, or proprietary development?

Comment: The other product just supports UWB, and it is not another DWM1001 board

Comment: My main problem has been trying to get a DWM1001 board communicating to a unique UWB device.

Answer (score 0):

Your main question seems to be how does a given UWB device know whether a radio packet is intended for it or for a different device.

For the devices you are using that comes down to the higher level firmware and device drivers used. The default will be for the radio to receive all of the packets that are being broadcast, these can then be checked to see if the to address in the radio packet matches the local ID. The parts you are using don't require any specific method of doing this, it is purely a software feature and so is up to you how to implement it.